# Что такое сигналы в Qt

Tags: qt, c++

То есть сигналы - по сути пустышка? И если написать свой класс и свои сигналы, то они не будут работать, пока не сгенерировать их с помощью emit?

**Обновление**

Вот [ссылка](http://pastebin.com/SiSSrT26), правда пример не мой.
Если там:

```
void Simple(const QString& str);
void Inversion(const QString& str);
void UpperCase(const QString& str);
void InversionAndUpperCase(const QString& str);
```

заменить `const QString& str` на `QString& str`, то работать не будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да. И пока не приконнектить к слотам. При определённом действии посылаешь сигнал и слот, с которым он соединён, начинает работать. Сигналом может быть любое событие, от нажатия кнопки до сигнала таймера или скачивания чего-то по сети. А слот, как правило, делает обработку этого события (например, по клику на кнопку он открывает новое окно - пожалуй, самый простой пример).

Comment: А почему работает только константная ссылка в параметрах объявления сигнала, а обычная нет?

Comment: Можно пример? Желательно на pastebin.

Comment: Вот [ссылка][1], правда пример не мой.
Если там :

    void Simple(const QString& str);
    void Inversion(const QString& str);
    void UpperCase(const QString& str);
    void InversionAndUpperCase(const QString& str);

 заменить `const QString& str` на `QString& str`, то работать не будет.


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/SiSSrT26